# Extract json data from an api array or matrix java android studio

Tags: java

I can't extract data from this json. I believe it is because it is an array. I read about it but I didn't find anything specific for this case.

I just need to take the values ​​individually each time I close {}.

Eg: result [0] .getLoterias();

== INSTANTANEA

The connection is being made normally, I just can't extract the data.

httpservice2.java

```
package br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.service;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.model.CEP2;

public class HttpService2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CEP2> {


    private final String cep;
    private final String token;

    public HttpService2(String cep, String token) {
        this.cep = token;
        this.token = cep;

    }

    @Override
    protected CEP2 doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();



            try {
                URL url = new URL( "A" + this.cep + "&token=" + this.token);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.connect();

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    resposta.append(scanner.next());
                }



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), CEP2.class);
    }



}
```

Main3Activity.java:

```
package br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.model.CEP2;
import br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.service.HttpService2;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


        final TextView resposta = findViewById(R.id.etMain_resposta2);
        final TextView cep = findViewById(R.id.etMain_resposta3);
        final TextView token = findViewById(R.id.etMain_resposta4);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String respostatoken = extras.getString("token");
        String respostaid = extras.getString("id");

        cep.setText(respostaid);
        token.setText(respostatoken);
//alert(cep.getText().toString() + token.getText().toString());
          try {
              CEP2 retorno = new HttpService2(cep.getText().toString(), token.getText().toString()).execute().get();
              String loteria = retorno.getIdloteria();
            resposta.setText(loteria);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void alert(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

CEP2.java:

```
package br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.model;



public class CEP2 {


    private String idloteria;

    public String getIdloteria() {
        return idloteria;
    }

    public void setIdloteria(String idloteria) {
        this.idloteria = idloteria;
    }



}
```

**currently:**

I changed

`return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), CEP2.class);`

per

```
Type cep2ListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CEP2>>(){}.getType();
List<CEP2> cep2List = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), cep2ListType);
return cep2List;
```

httpservic2 new:

```
package br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.service;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.model.CEP2;

public class HttpService2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, CEP2> {


    private final String cep;
    private final String token;

    public HttpService2(String cep, String token) {
        this.cep = token;
        this.token = cep;

    }

    @Override
    protected CEP2 doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();



            try {
                URL url = new URL( "A" + this.cep + "&token=" + this.token);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.connect();

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    resposta.append(scanner.next());
                }



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



               Type cep2ListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CEP2>>(){}.getType();
        List<CEP2> cep2List = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), cep2ListType);
        return cep2List;
    }



}
```

**I need to change the return from doinbackground However, I'm lost**

Comment: Your cep2 class only contains a string attribute, but your json looks a bit more complicated. I really don't see how these two things are supposed to work together?!

Comment: I just need a value of that json(idloteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want the idloteria from the response which should be fine. But as you say it's an array and it should be parsed as an array or a List.

The:

```
return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), CEP2.class);
```

Should be

```
Type cep2ListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CEP2>>(){}.getType();
List<CEP2> cep2List = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), cep2ListType);
return cep2List;
```

If you want the response be parsed as a list.

Another possibility is to get the data parsed as an array:

```
CEP2[] cep2Array = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), CEP2[].class);
return cep2Array;
```

and you'll need to change the return of the doInBackground in accordance with the response type you choose.

Lets choose to return a list. In this case change `AsyncTask<Void, Void, CEP2>` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<CEP2>>` and also `protected CEP2 doInBackground` to `protected List<CEP2> doInBackground`.
The returned list will be received in onPostExecute parameter `onPostExecute(List<CEP2> cep2List)`. And in this onPostExecute you can save the list, print it or do whatever you want to do with the received data.

But keep in mind that [AsyncTask are deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) in API level R. It's recommended using standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I haven't programmed on android for a long time, I believe you noticed with the use of AsyncTaks that it is already obsolete. I understood the concept and did some tests, but I never passed a matrix and I have no idea what to put in the return of doInBackground. Could you help me with that too? thankful

Comment: No problem, I've updated the answer with more info about this. If you still need more help/info tomorrow and nobody has provided it yet I'll try to help you, here is late and I have to wake up soon tomorrow.

Comment: Everything is fine, but the connection fails when I switch to (app closes): CEP2 retorno = new HttpService2(cep.getText().toString(), token.getText().toString()).execute().get();                                                                                   for                                                                                                                         List<CEP2> retorno = new HttpService2(cep.getText().toString(), token.getText().toString()).execute().get();

Comment: Could you provide the [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this/23353174#23353174) of that last crash?

Comment: https://github.com/mateusanjost/teste-pilha.git   or  at       at br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.service.HttpService2.doInBackground(HttpService2.java:65)
        at br.com.matheuscastiglioni.blog.requisicao_http.service.HttpService2.doInBackground(HttpService2.java:20) ? P.S: it is the first time that I do a stack trace in android studio, I hope I did it correctly. Thank you

Comment: Line: public class HttpService2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<CEP2>> {

 and      List<CEP2> cep2List = new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), cep2ListType);